# Verify string is in valid format in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-matching

How to check if string is valid (Alphanumerical values only) and

```
string does not "CompanyName"
string does not contain ban keywords
string does not contain spaces or return or tabs
string does not contain special characters
```

Comment: string does not company name? What does that mean? And does not contain ban keywords? Do you mean banned keywords?

Comment: Yes the string can not contain a list of specified banned keywords, which includes specified company names.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is clearly a case for custom validation. First, check for alphanumeric characters using a regex (if that check passes, it won't contain spaces, tabs or returns or special characters). Then go through your ban keywords. If one is found break and return failure.

Answer (score 0):

something like that should check for Alphanumerical values not sure if it the best way

```
    Regex reg = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");

if (reg.IsMatch(stringpassed))
{

}
```

and than some custom validation

Comment: Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"); <-- what does that *$ do?)